# Future tenses use 1

Tags: future-continuous

1 I will play games next week

2 I will be playing games next week

Both are grammatically correct but second is unlikely unless I specify time like for two hours or add additional activity like " I will be playing and she will be cooking" Am I right?

Comment: You have been asking a lot of questions re tenses. This site has loads of entries on most of these. The difference is not about specifying time. As this has been answered in many answers, the mods will probably close this as a duplicate.

Comment: So it is ok to say for example I will be working next next week without adding anythinlike when John comes . We can do it just to show it's ongoing.  Yes? Please answer that and I don't ask any similar questions anymore

Comment: [corrections: and I won't ask any similar questions//Is it okay to say etc.] Think about the logic of the progressive tenses: I'm working now. And I will be working next week.

Comment: So yes or no?..